# can't delete tk widgets

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want the tk code to delete the following widgets. Is it destroy?

```
Entry .scW.sf.frame.entry -background "#ffffff"
Button .scW.sf.frame.Button -command "open"

grid .scW.sf.frame.entry -in .scW.sf.frame -row 17 -column 2 -sticky ""
grid .scW.sf.frame.Button -in .scW.sf.frame -row 17 -column 3 -sticky "w"
```

Comment: I advise never starting a component of a widget name with a capital letter (`Button`); those are reserved for widget class names in various places, and that can cause confusion.

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to get rid of a widget entirely is with `destroy`:

```
destroy .scW.sf.frame.entry .scW.sf.frame.Button
```

It can take any number of widget names. It's often easiest to group the things that live together within a frame that is destroyed, as widgets are destroyed when their parent is destroyed, but that's not necessary.